# Vertical centering of links in a menu with variable height

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a menu and a CSS as shown below and to play around also on http://codepen.io/Sofian777/pen/PqeyQa

I need to vertical align the menu items and tried all kind of things with vertical-align:middle and different display: settings on li and a (because it online works on inline elements) but I couldn't get it to work.

Anybody knows how to achieve this?

Edit: This is just a simplified scenario that I thought will be enough, but it wasn't, so here is my full scenario: http://codepen.io/Sofian777/pen/NqMOom (see short description in my comment to the answer of GolezTrol)

```
<div id="menu"> 
      <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
</div> 

#menu {background: CornflowerBlue; 
  width: 100%;}

#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none; 
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
} 

#menu ul li {
    display: inline; 
    text-align: center;
}

#menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 100%;
    background: RoyalBlue;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `:before` to help alignment.

```css
   html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}


html {font-size:62.5%}
body {font-size: 16px; max-width: 1000px; margin: auto; line-height: 1.618;}
#menu {background: CornflowerBlue; 
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%; 
  padding-bottom: 5.6%; /* defining our 1000px : 56px ratio of the menubar */;}

#menu ul {
    position: absolute; right: 0; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; /* This additional container is needed to not add the content to the padding-trick for our aspect ratio. */
    list-style-type: none; 
    text-align: center;
} 

#menu ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline; 
    text-align: center;
}

#menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 20%; 
    height: 100%;
    background: RoyalBlue;
}
#menu ul li a:before{
    height: 100%;
width: 1px;
display: inline-block;
content: '';
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
    <div id="menu"> 
  <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: OMG This is genious and solving my issue perfectly perfect. Thank you, I didn't hope that this exceptional rare scenario will find a fully automated solution. Thanks a lot. I cannot upvote I dont have 15 reputation yet. I will come back another day :)

Answer (score 1):

The main change is setting the line height to the height of the element, so to 50px in this case.

Furthermore you can move some of the properties to the links. By doing so, the `ul` and `li` size with the links, and you don't need to duplicate those properties:

```css
#menu {
  background: CornflowerBlue;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  background: RoyalBlue;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is perfect for what I described here. Actually what I need is more complicated and I thought of keeping it simple for my question, but I see now that I need to put the full story. I am about to create a fluid layout in which the menubar as also other elements have to keep a certain propotion of width to height at each screen size. I use the padding-bottom trick to achieve this, resize your browser to see the behaviour. Now I just need to get the text in the center of the block. Any idea for this scenario? http://codepen.io/Sofian777/pen/NqMOom

Comment: I wanted to give you a vote up but i dont have 15 reputation yet. So thanks for the moment, your answer was perfectly answering my initial simplified question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `line-height`:

```
#menu {background: CornflowerBlue; 
  width: 100%;}

#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none; 
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
} 

#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align: center;
}

#menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block; 
    width: 200px; 
    background: RoyalBlue;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KittMedia/3q7a9h7x/)

Comment: Thanks to you as well, your answer is the very basic of Golez Trol's who even improved the code around it.